# Create / Update and other SQL commands denied to user

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I'm using Grails cloud foundry plugin. After app starts I'm getting following exceptions

```
2012-05-19 08:34:09,179 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: create 
table article_content (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not null, 
comments LONGTEXT, content LONGTEXT, date_created datetime not null, failure bit 
not null, tags varchar(255), title varchar(255), url varchar(500) not null, 
primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB 

2012-05-19 08:34:09,181 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - CREATE command denied 
to user 'uozOL0LSfBM3u'@'172.30.50.25' for table 'article_content'
```

Using dbConsole and CloudFoundry properties I connected to db, tried to execute SQL command and obtained same exception.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the `create table...` command using the vmc tunnel feature? http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

I was able to execute the SQL on a MySQL service provisioned on my Cloud Foundry account. If that doesn't help, can you link to a zip of your app, so I can download and try to reproduce the issue?